# TSQL MERGE command appears to not actually merge

Tags: t-sql, merge

I'm studying the code [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

When I cut-n-paste the following code from there:

-- MERGE statement with the join conditions specified correctly.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

It produces the output they say, BUT it doesn't actually change the TARGET table.  How do I get it to actually change the results of the TARGET table?  Is there some kind of switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `ROLLBACK TRAN;`  with a `COMMIT TRAN;`

The target table is being changed hence you seeing the correct `OUTPUT` but then you are undoing it in the next statement by rolling back the transaction.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!  Will check when time elapses.